# Windows 10 gone after (Re-)Installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have two partitions with Windows 10 on one and Ubuntu 14.04 on the other. 
Today (after some time) I booted into ubuntu and made some bigger update which ended with a crash. After that ubuntu was totally broken, Windows still could be started.

I inserted the 14.04 installation disc and selected the option where it says something like there was an ubuntu found would you like to overwrite it. I thouhgt this would overwrite the ubuntu partition to fix the totally broken ubuntu.

After installation I guess my windows is gone but I still hope it is just a grub issue or something else.

How could I evaluate if windows is still there? I just want to be sure that everything is lost before I start reinstalling everything -.-

Thankes in advance,
carsten.

Comment: check the partition if the windows file still exists?

Comment: Sorry I am not so familiar with ubuntu I am not sure where to find that... tried a couple of things but still am not sure :-(

Comment: can you view the partition where windows was installed??

Comment: no i dont see it under devices in the file manager there is only the ubuntu partition

Comment: Did you use a new 14.04.5 s(fixed) or an older version? Old versions had major bug: Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows or any other partitions.
Sept 2014 Fix being released for one drive installs, but multiple drive installs must use Something Else. And fix is not in current versions. Perhaps in 15.04.
this bug was fixed in the package ubiquity - 2.18.8.3 jan 2015
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, I've used 14.04.1 :-(

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you need to make sure you didn't remove the partition. Boot with the Ubuntu DVD and then, in the dash, search for Gparted. Once started, it will show you the available partitions on your hard drive. At least one if not two NTFS partitions should be there. If you have none, then Windows 10 is gone. Can you confirm to us what you're seeing (you can post a screenshot if it's easier).

Comment: Thanks Daniel... I did exactly what you wrote and got this:

https://postimg.org/image/4b8ij6p9b/

Comment: That's odd. I have never seen crypt-luks before. Nonetheless the FAT32 partition COULD be it.  If I understood correctly, you have access to your Ubuntu install now right? If so you can try using the "Terminal way" here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: No unfortunately this didn't work and I guess the FAT32 partition was created by windows before (but the actual windows was NTFS).

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I just saw that the FAT32 partition had only 13 MB used. I think you've lost your Windows partition unfortunately. :(

Comment: Looks like it's lost... well at least all my personal data is also stored on a NAS ;-)
But I have to reinstall everything... well my fault ;-)
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Ahh! Nice, at least you won't lose anything more than time! ;-)